# how to add video as background

Tags: html, css, reactjs, web, responsive-design

in this file initially I created such a logic where the background images changes on each reload but no I want something different. I want to play a video in the background, and the video is in my local storage(Public folder). Project is based on react. please help me with code also help me to figure out the CSS part. Code is attached below.

```
import './App.css';
import Footer from './Components/Footer';
import Header from './Components/Header';
function App() {
  // let imageArr = ["back.jpg", "front.jpg", "right.jpg"];
  // let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageArr.length);
  // let randomImage = imageArr[randomNum];
  return (
    // <div className="App" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${randomImage})`}}>


      <div className='container'>
        <div className='container'>
          <Header />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </div>

    // </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this it works!

Html:
<iframe
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/E7wJTI-1dvQ"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"
        allowfullscreen
        title="video"
      />

Css:
iframe {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 56.25vw; /* Given a 16:9 aspect ratio, 9/16*100 = 56.25 */
 min-height: 100vh;
 min-width: 177.77vh; /* Given a 16:9 aspect ratio, 16/9*100 = 177.77 */
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-swartz-9196lu?file=/src/App.js